# Why can't I transform a distribution by deducting one from all counts?

Tags: distributions

Suppose I have records of the number of fishes that each fisherman caught from a particular lake within the year. The distribution peaks at count = 1 (i.e. most fishermen caught just one fish from the lake in the year), tapers off after that, and has a long right-tail (a very small number of fishermen caught over 100 fishes).

Such a data could possibly fit either a Poisson Distribution or a Negative Binomial Distribution. However, both of these distributions have a non-zero probability at count = 0, whereas for our data, fishermen who caught no fishes were not captured as a data point.

Why is it not correct to transform our original data by just deducting 1 from all counts, and therefore shifting our distribution to the left by 1 such that there is now a non-zero probability at count = 0?

(I think the correct answer to how to deal with the absence of count = 0 is to use a zero-trauncated distribution instead)

Comment: There's nothing "incorrect" about it -- you're just expressing the same values in a mathematically equivalent way.  The issue, though, is whether this re-expression accomplishes anything.  If the resulting data are closely described by a Poisson [French: "fish"!] distribution, then you have learned something.  If not, that might cause you to reconsider your strategy; to back up; and think of applying a more systematic, principled approach to your analysis, as you intimate at the end of this question.

Comment: the distribution doesn't sound like Poisson (fish) to me. Can't see it having peak at 1 and non-trivial probability of 100 at the same time.

Comment: @whuber The context here is that this question came up to me in an interview for a data science job. The interviewer asked me how to deal with the issue of the absence of count = 0, and I proposed transforming the data. Was told by the interviewer that transforming it is the wrong thing to do, but I didn't quite catch the explanation.

Comment: As a general proposition, your interviewer was incorrect.  For instance, you could frame your approach as fitting a model of the form $\Pr(X)=f(X+\delta;\lambda)$ where $f(;\lambda)$ is a family of discrete distributions and $\delta$ is an integer offset.  It would help if you could supply reasons why such a model might be plausible, but even absent such justification, there's nothing overtly wrong with using such models.  Your interviewer's perspective eliminates the possibility of such creative approaches.  We can speculate about what that does for their company's prospects ;-).

Comment: I;m curious as to who in the company wrote the question and who administered the question.  I know in some large companies, interviews (even technical ones) are given by an HR person, who may just have the question and an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Two possibilities occur to me:

- Possibly there were many who caught no fish, and they were excluded from the data because they caught no fish. Suppose you try to model the situation via some parametrized family of probability distributions supported on the set $\{ 0, 1, 2, 3, \ldots \}.$ From the form of the probability mass function, you can find the conditional probability distribution given that the value is at least $1.$ That gives you a parametrized family, and you can then estimate the parameter based on the data. Your estimated value of the parameter will result in an estimated value of the probability of catching $0$ fish.
- Maybe everyone kept at it until they caught at least one fish, and then many of them were satisfied. If so, then using some family of distributions supported on the set $\{ 1,2,3,\ldots\}$ would make more sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can fit whatever you like if it works for you.

A problem is that any of the mechanistic motivations and interpretations behind the Poisson distribution and the negative binomial distribution are lost when you do it this way. (Not saying that it is otherwise guaranteed, but in this way you can be sure that there is likely no strong reason to use these distributions).

Comment: To carry on in a similar way as whuber's remark that 'poisson' means 'fish' in French:  if you subtract one from the Poisson distribution then you get 'poison' and it kills the distribution.